# Remap keycodes of Kensington presentation remote buttons

Tags: keyboard, presentations

I have a Kensington presentation remote. When I activate the laser it sends the keycode for F5. I have my slides in HTML and open them with Firefox so F5 causes a refresh and returns me to the first slide. Is there a way for me to modify the Kensington so that it doesn't send F5 when the button is pressed?

Here is the output from `xev`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xd5, subw 0x0, time 10072399, (186,-165), root:(251,425),
    state 0x0, keycode 71 (keysym 0xffc2, F5), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xd5, subw 0x0, time 10072511, (186,-165), root:(251,425),
    state 0x0, keycode 71 (keysym 0xffc2, F5), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: sounds more like a hardware error. F5 in PowerPoint would start the presentation from the first slide. Check your remote for dust or similar things. I would suppose it should not send F5 when you press the laser.

Comment: It does seem like an odd thing for it to do.

Comment: looks like you can only disable the key F5 in general from your OS. Then pressing F5 on any keyboard would no longer do anything.

Comment: Yes, I could always do that when I want to give a presentation.